# Zabbix global all trigger dependency

Tags: triggers, dependencies, zabbix

I have Zabbix server at home, connected via not 100% stable 4G link. And i would like some kind of global trigger dependency (or lets say alert dependency) that i will be not notified about errors while internet not present.

Because most monitored hosts and web services are outside of my network. In cases when there is WAN problems (lte link down etc.) zabbix collects a failed trigger alerts and cannot tries to notify me about them (stores in email queue). After some time internet goes back to norm and i receive PROBLEM and immediately OK messages about every test zabbix couldn't perform during that period. So it ends up in huge email storm after WAN restores.

I know that i can set up dependency on each trigger. But have about ~100 hosts + ~1000 triggers.

Answer (score 0):

zabbix cannot normally handle this situation, look better at nagios/check-mk. there are dependencies between hosts.